# Как повесить событие на все кнопки на странице?

Tags: javascript, html

как повесить событие на всё( где используется буттон)

Comment: положить их все в массив и пройтись циклом?

Comment: @Silento что за тайминг сам хотел написать((

Answer (score 3, accepted):

можно сделать с использованием jQuery:

```
jQuery(".className").click(functionName);
```

html-разметка:

```
<button class="className">1</button>
<button class="className">2</button>
<button class="className">3</button>
```

Answer (score 4):

> Как повесить событие на все кнопки на странице?

Вот так:

```js
// Выбираем все кнопки на странице и получаем массив
var btns = document.querySelectorAll('button')
// Проходим по массиву
btns.forEach(function(btn) {
  // Вешаем событие клик
  btn.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    console.log('Button clicked' + e.target.classList);
  })
})
```

```html
<button class="btn-1">1</button>
<button class="btn-2">2</button>
<button class="btn-3">3</button>
<button class="btn-4">4</button>
<button class="btn-5">5</button>
```

Comment: Приветствую. Можно же  делегировать родителю. :)  Будет всего один обработчик, а так у Вас целых 5  пополнили очередь.

Comment: @Qwerty_Wasd приветствую. делегировать родителю с целью прослушки всех дочерних элементов или потом выделять на кого реагировать, а на кого нет?

Comment: В зависимости от преследуемой цели - если нужно одно действие на всех, можно дать им один класс и  e.target.classList.contains() возьмет их

Answer (score 2):

Как вариант делегировать родителю, чтобы не гадить в очередь.
**Если нужно одно действие на всех, то**

```js
document.body.addEventListener('click', e => {
  if (e.target.classList.contains('classes')) alert(1);
})
```

```html
<button class="classes">Один</button>
<button class="classes">Два</button>
<button class="classes">Три</button>
<button class="classes">Четыре</button>
<button class="classes">Пять</button>
```

**Если нужно разделить задачи, то**

```js
document.body.addEventListener('click', e => {
  if (e.target.classList.contains('one')) alert(`Я выполню задачу ${e.target.textContent}`);
  if (e.target.classList.contains('two')) alert(`Я выполню задачу ${e.target.textContent}`)
  //и так далее
});
```

```html
<button class="classes one">Один</button>
<button class="classes two">Два</button>
<button class="classes three">Три</button>
<button class="classes four">Четыре</button>
<button class="classes five">Пять</button>
```